# Use public key created in windows 10 machine with docker apache image

Tags: windows, git, docker, ssh

I'm developing on a windows 10 machine (company policy :( ) I use docker which creates an apache image to develop locally as the website is linux.  I have created an SSH key on my local windows machine.  If I'm using git in the /var/www folder on docker, how do I use my public key to pull and push from a git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy/mount the ssh key directory into your container.

If you are git cloning with a `RUN` command in your dockerfile, you need to `ADD` the .ssh directory into the container, with something like:

```
ADD <path-to-id_rsa-dir-on-windows> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you are git cloning when starting the container, you can mount the ssh directory into the container.

Comment: Thanks, I can do a 'docker build' and this works with your suggestions.  However git pull still asks for my username and password.  How do I check if the public key is running on the docker 'var/www/' container where the website is hosted?